# Speed up Select Operating on a Large List with Multiple Criteria

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering

I am using the following code to select stocks that have performance data starting before one specified date and ending after a second specified date, as follows:

```
 universe = 
  Association@
   Table[<|monthDates[[idate]] -> 
      Select[allStocks, 
       EntityPerformanceStartDate[#] <= monthDates[[idate]] && 
         EntityPerformanceEndDate[#] >= 
          monthDates[[idate + 1]] &]|>, {idate, Length[monthDates]-1}];
```

allStocks is a list of several thousand stock entities.  The EntityPerformanceStartDate and EntityPerformanceEndDate functions identify the first and last dates in the time series of performance data for a specified entity.  monthDates is a list of DateObjects that might be 100-200 in length.

The code is slow to execute and cannot be parallelized with ParallelTable for some reason (why not?).

Can anyone suggest a faster method for selection using multiple criteria like this?

Comment: Can you show us the `EntityPerformance(...)Date` functions? The fact that they must be called for every element of `allStocks` for each element in your `Table` is almost guaranteed the bottleneck here.

Comment: Could you please add a small example of `allStocks` and  `monthDates`